# Unexpected key 'MessageDeduplicationID' found in params aws-sdk SQS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have the following code:

```
const sqs = new aws.SQS({region: 'us-east-1', apiVersion: '2012-11-05'});
...
const result = await sqs.sendMessage({
      MessageBody: JSON.stringify(item),
      QueueUrl: QUEUE_URL,
      MessageGroupId: groupId,
      MessageDeduplicationID: deduplicationId,
}).promise();
```

and I'm receiving this error:
`Unexpected key 'MessageDeduplicationID' found in params`

My aws sdk in dev dependencies is `"aws-sdk": "^2.692.0",`

I've tried changing the apiVersion to `2020-01-09` and also tried no apiVersion passed but same result.

By the way the `MessageDeduplicationID` is part of an update to [support sqs triggers on FIFO queues](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-release-notes.html) on November 25, 2019 as said on that doc. But I can't seem to make it work :(

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: It's `MessageDeduplicationId`, not `MessageDeduplicationID`. These property/key names are case sensitive. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SQS.html#sendMessage-property

Comment: ooh totally missed the first step - **double check**. Thanks @404 :) please put your comment as answer so I can mark as correct. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key or property names in the params object for all AWS SDK functions are case sensitive. In your case you supplied `MessageDeduplicationID`, but as per [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SQS.html#sendMessage-property) it should be `MessageDeduplicationId`, hence the validation error about an unexpected key.